# How to store time duration values in MySQL as the TIME datatype?

Tags: mysql, sql, time, duration

I need to store song durations in minutes/seconds, I need to use TIME, but how would I refer to a certain duration when I am writing an INSERT statement? My datatype in the table is already TIME, should I just STR_TO_DATE the string value of "4:29"?

Comment: I would strongly suggest using an integer with the total number of seconds if at all possible. You'll probably save yourself some headaches later. Curious as to the reason for the requirement to use a `TIME` field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, take a look here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/time.html

> Be careful about assigning abbreviated values to a TIME column. MySQL
>   interprets abbreviated TIME values with colons as time of the day.
>   That is, '11:12' means '11:12:00', not '00:11:12'. MySQL interprets
>   abbreviated values without colons using the assumption that the two
>   rightmost digits represent seconds (that is, as elapsed time rather
>   than as time of day). For example, you might think of '1112' and 1112
>   as meaning '11:12:00' (12 minutes after 11 o'clock), but MySQL
>   interprets them as '00:11:12' (11 minutes, 12 seconds). Similarly,
>   '12' and 12 are interpreted as '00:00:12'.

So, if you wanna insert a song with duration = 05:55, just write this:

```
insert into songs (duration) values('0555');
```