# When using the SUM() function, how does MySQL add times?

Tags: mysql

In my database, I have a field called flighttime. It contains durations of flights, ie: 1:31, 0:45, 0:29. When I use the SUM() function of MySQL to add those times, it gives me a strange number, XXXXX. It isn't in the time format like one would expect XX:XX.

Anyone know exactly how MySQL adds times? If so, how can I convert the number it gives me to the format like XX:XX?

Thanks!

Comment: What column type are you using to store the flight durations?

Comment: I'm using the Time datatype.

Comment: Alright, then have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067939/how-to-store-time-duration-values-in-mysql-as-the-time-datatype

Comment: I agree, you should store it as an integer, especially if you want to sum it in the sql.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to add times, unless they are relative.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add times in mysql you should use `ADDTIME()` function in mysql not the `SUM()` function.

```
mysql> SELECT ADDTIME('2007-12-31 23:59:59.999999', '1 1:1:1.000002');
    -> '2008-01-02 01:01:01.000001'
mysql> SELECT ADDTIME('01:00:00.999999', '02:00:00.999998');
    -> '03:00:01.999997'
```

The synatx is `ADDTIME(expr1,expr2)`  So you cant add three times together.

Comment: `select now(), addtime(now(), concat('1:35', ':00'));` will add 1:35. [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/33062/5)

Comment: of course there are workarounds to add multiple times together. I said according to syntax you cant add many times

Comment: I'm getting the error message 'Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'ADDTIME' with this function.

Comment: Can you show your code. I think you are adding three times together in the function. You can only add two. The parameter count should be two.

Comment: Oh I see now. I'm trying to add a whole column of times together. Not just three or four.

Comment: So you should use some loops or sub queries to achieve that.